# Enqueue script taking no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've added my custom_script.js to my child theme by making a js folder in the directory, and I added it within my function.php like this.

```
/*** Make Header Shrink on Page Scroll**/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scroll_enqueue_script',15 );
function scroll_enqueue_script() {
wp_register_script('scroll_custom_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array('jquery'), '4.3.1', true);

wp_enqueue_script('scroll_custom_script');
}
```

I see the script through the developer console in my elements, and in my resources I can see the code. However it doesn't seem to trigger. I made an alert on scroll to test if it would fire and I can't seem to get it to trigger.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(function(){
var hasBeenTrigged = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100 && !hasBeenTrigged) { // if scroll is greater/equal then 100 and hasBeenTrigged is set to false.
        alert("You've scrolled 100 pixels.");
        hasBeenTrigged = true;
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: What does the console say? Is your script listed before  jQuery in the document?

Comment: `$(function() {` is a redundant shorthand for `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Austin It was appearing a few scripts before jquery/ui/core.min.js script. But after I changed it to the 15 in "add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scroll_enqueue_script',15 " it started after in the script. So currently the custom_script.js appears towards the end of the elements underneath the core.min.js

Comment: Removed the "$(function() { " redundancy, still not triggering though :(

Comment: checked the console via document.body.scrollTop and it always returns 0...even when I'm scrolling